# Todo List - "right detail" cell style to show item count

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm learning swift and IOS development and I'm creating a todo list where I'm trying to show the number of items in the category in a right detail cell style. I have managed to get it working however when it runs its shows as having 0 items in the category despite having 3 or more. 
I am using realm to persist my data and I have a seperate `CategoryViewController` and a `TodoListViewController`.

Can anybody help me? I can't figure out where I've gone wrong and it's taken me days just to get this far!

**CategoryViewController:**

```
class CategoryViewController: SwipeTableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var categoryarray: Results<Category>?
    var todoItems: Results<Item>?
    var todoVC = TodoListViewController()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

        if let category = categoryarray?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = category.name
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: category.colour)
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = ContrastColorOf(UIColor(hexString: category.colour)!, returnFlat: true)
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(todoItems?.count ?? 0)"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to show number of items for certain category. So do it just like you set name etc. Set text of `detailTextLabel` as number of items of list property of `Category`

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(category.todoItems.count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have been staring at this for days and not been able to figure it out. You're a legend!